# Where can I learn about the Riemann Zeta function/Riemann Hyposthesis?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, riemann-hypothesis

I've been very curious about the Riemann zeta function and the Riemann hypothesis and I have been wanting to learn about it on a deeper level for a while now. While I don't intend to understand everything, I want to have a pretty good understanding of it. The main factor limiting me isI've only completed courses up to Calculus. Are there any elementary sources/books/papers that I can read to get some informatino about the zeta function and necessary topics to understand it? I don't need everything, just a general overview

Comment: Honestly, you should next learn the basics of complex analysis. Any explanations of the RH that don't use analytic continuation are going to be very superficial.

Comment: It's probably worth reading [The Music of the Primes](https://www.amazon.com/Music-Primes-Searching-Greatest-Mathematics/dp/0062064010) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

To get a "good understanding" you will need at bare minimum an elementary knowledge of number theory and complex analysis. If you just want a casual introductory book, [Prime Obsession](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0452285259) by John Derbyshire is probably what you are looking for; but, assuming you have a basic background knowledge of the Riemann Hypothesis (which I believe is implied), you may find [this paper](http://sections.maa.org/epadel/awards/studentpaper/winners/2011_Yoder.pdf) useful, as it introduces the basic concepts concisely and simply. After that, I would recommend [Riemann's Zeta Function](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486417409) by H. M. Edwards, but it is geared towards undergraduates so it may be too advanced for you.

There are some simple conjectures that happen to be equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis, however, these can be very misleading as they more or less hide their complexity. A good example is Robin's inequality: given $\gamma$ as the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\sigma(n)$ the [divisor function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html), the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the following inequality for $n > 5040$:

$$
\sigma(n) < e^\gamma n \log\log{n}
$$

A similar bound on the divisor function was also shown to be equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis by Jeffrey Lagarias:

$$
\sigma(n) < H_n + e^{H_n}\log{H_n} \hspace{1em}\text{for } H_n = \sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}
$$

Modern approaches to the Riemann hypothesis require an advanced understanding of numerous fields in mathematics. I'm not aware of any books that cover modern developments on the RH, so for advanced information you probably have to read a bunch of papers. A proof of the RH will probably use extremely advanced techniques in multiple areas of mathematics, similar to the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: It is people's individual choices if they want to consider an author's non-mathematical works when deciding if they want to read/buy their mathematical works, but if this is a factor for you, you might want to read more about Derbyshire (maybe his Wikipedia page?) before going with his book.